# How to improve performance of merging continuous heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory

I wrote a heap manager simulator. I used two list to keep address and size of allocated and free blocks.
I found that the following function drastically degrade my code performance since I need to allocate million object…
The aim of this function is to find continuous free block in a heap and merge them but the problem is that there is a linear search in it and as a result it take long time to do that(more than 1 hour)
How can I improve it? Any ideas?

```
public void updateFreeList(tuple freeElement)
{
  int i=0;
  if(freeList.size()> 1)
  {
    while(i<freeList.size())
    {
      try{
        if((freeList.get(i).getAddress()+freeList.get(i).getSize()) == (freeList.get(i+1).getAddress()))
        {
          freeList.get(i).setSize(freeList.get(i).getSize() + freeList.get(i+1).getSize());
          freeList.remove(i+1);
          continue;
        }
        i++;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
       break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following observation: two blocks can be merged only if one of them has just been deallocated. That's why there is no need to check the entire list: when you deallocate a block and return it to a free blocks list, you need to check only the previous and the next block.

Comment: But it is on the list, So I need to traverse the freeList to find previous and next block. For example in the freeList i have (50,50)(300,100)(700,100)(1000,200) and want to free (100,200) so I need to traverse the freeList to find the next and previous. So still there is a linear search? Am I right?

Comment: @user2942756 If you do not maintain any additional data structure to speed up the search, it is linear. However, if having an additional logarithm factor for each operation is feasible, you can maintain a `TreeSet` of blocks so that you can find the next and the previous one in `O(log N)` time.